# VBA, change part of date in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large sheet of data where i need to change the date (day) in 4 or 5 columns to match the date (day) in another column. For example in 'H' i have 16/05/15 etc. and in the other columns all the days are the 1st of the same month. I would like to change the day '1' to the same day '16' as in column 'H' it will take me hours to do, can anyone help me out with some code that would do it for me?

Thanks.

Comment: SO is NOT `Write code for me site`. Show us what have you tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: If this is a one-off, you could just write a formula in a temporary column that calculates `DATE` using the `YEAR` and `MONTH` of the original cell and the `DAY` of column H (watching out for 29th of Feb in non-leap years, if the year in H is different to the year in the other cell), and then "paste values" that result back over your original cells.

Comment: @YowE3K Why don't you post this comment as a solution? Even if the OP might not be in favor of this approach you should keep in mind that SO is (more importantly) a great reference library for others looking for solutions. In short: even if I cannot accept it as an answer I'd up-vote it and would greatly appreciate finding such a solution (awesome quick-fix). Also, you might get a great badge for an up-voted answer on a down-voted question (if you don't have that yet).

Comment: I'll give the formula a go, i had thought of doing this but thought code may have done it a bit quicker, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Ralph - Not sure whether I like giving a "work-around" as an "answer", but have succumbed to your pleading ( :D ) and have done so.

Comment: @ralph - I finally found the badges page again (not easy with the new menu!) and the badge you are probably talking about is "Reversal" for "Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score".  As my highest scoring answer so far is a whopping +6 I can't image me getting that badge any time soon.  I doubt if I will ever even get a "Nice answer" badge!  :D

Comment: @YowE3K Give it a year or two. None of the 200+ up-voted answers got those votes in a day. They come in over time. Most 20k+ users get more and more reputation every day just with all their old answers. Patience is a virtue. ;) Keeping that thought in mind you yourself should use your daily 40 up-votes per day to appreciate other's work. Let me show you what I mean....

Comment: @Ralph - I'm old - I don't have time for patience!  (And who wants to be virtuous !!?!?!) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one-off, you could just write a formula in a temporary column that calculates `DATE` using the `YEAR` and `MONTH` of the original cell and the `DAY` of column H (watching out for 29th of Feb in non-leap years, if the year in H is different to the year in the other cell), and then "paste values" that result back over your original cells.

For example, assuming data you want to change is currently in K2, then place the following formula in X2 (or wherever else you like):

```
=IF(MONTH(DATE(YEAR(K2),MONTH(K2),DAY(H2)))<>MONTH(K2),
    DATE(YEAR(K2),MONTH(K2)+1,0),
    DATE(YEAR(K2),MONTH(K2),DAY(H2)))
```